# Is a separate Delphi XE4 license required for a build machine?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe4

For building applications via **dcc32** onto build server I could use Delphi Trial. There wasn't any problems with licenses for such approach.

Now, I am going to use building Delphi XE4 applications onto TeamCity via **msbuild**.

Do I need to have a separate license Delphi XE4 reguired for a build machine?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `license.rtf` file distributed with XE4:

> 2.4. Command Line Compiler. Licensee may install the command line compiler on a separate computer from the Product itself, provided that the sole purpose of doing so is to allow that computer to perform unattended building of applications.  The Command Line Compiler shall not be considered a ‘redistributable’.

So the answer is "No, you don't need a separate license to install the command line compiler on a build machine."