# How to install Delphi 10.2 Tokyo command line compiler

Tags: delphi, azure-pipelines, delphi-10.2-tokyo

We are in the process of setting up builds for delphi projects, is there a way to only install Delphi 10.2 command line compiler on the build server which will be used only for building delphi projects using VSTS builds.

Comment: Why don't you install Delphi and use the command line compiler? Do you have actual problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: umm, because they are creating a build server and don't need the full IDE? Says so right in the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes you are right, we do not need the full IDE on the build server.

Comment: Just ignore it. You don't have to run it. What is the problem with that? Is it worth trying to hack out bits of the deployed product?

Comment: Do we need to install the licensed version of Delphi on the build server, just to generate CI builds

Comment: Yes you do. It needs to be registered too.

Comment: @Santhosh Do you solve this issue with Andrei's solution?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes, have accepted the answer.

Comment: The Embarcadero C++ Builder has option to only [install compiler tool](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler). This is very nice for a DockerFile for example

Comment: @David Heffernan Wouldn't installing Delphi violate the license terms, which state that "Licensee may install the command line compiler on a separate computer from the Product itself, provided that the sole purpose of doing so is to allow that computer to perform unattended building of applications."

Comment: @R.J. I don't think so

Comment: @David Heffernan Installing RAD Studio may breach the license's allowed installs. For 11.3, Embarcadero recommended xcopy deployment, which enables use of the command line tools but not the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi installation package doesn't have such option. Install full version, use command line compiler only. **You don't need extra license** and probably don't even need to activate (but it is allowed as long as you use command line tools for unattended builds only). Licensing issue discussed here: [Is a separate Delphi XE4 license required for a build machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402025/is-a-separate-delphi-xe4-license-required-for-a-build-machine)

Comment: I have another question, we have couple of build servers where full version of Delphi installation is available and the licenses would be expiring very soon. That is when we came up with the idea to install command line compiler alone on the new build servers, now that it is not possible to do so, can we go ahead and use the build servers just to build the projects via MsBuild even after license expiry?

Comment: Licenses don't expire

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, Yes you are correct the licenses does not expire, but the subscription does. In that case can we use the setup for unattended CI builds?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you.

Comment: The license says "Licensee may install the command line compiler on a separate computer from the Product itself, provided that the sole purpose of doing so is to allow that computer to perform unattended building of applications." That appears not to include the rest of RAD Studio.